# "Darkening" a colour so that it's equivalent to the original when made transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, css, transparency

When you make a colour partly transparent, it lightens (assuming it's on a white background), naturally. I would like to counter this behaviour by "darkening" a colour, so that when I make it transparent, when on a white background, the end result is the same as the original colour.

Basically, I would like to compensate the effect of transparency. And I have no idea of how I would do that. I've tried playing with some numbers in the colour's parameters, but I haven't been able to find what I should do.

This might be hard to understand in words alone, so I've made a visual explanation of what I would like to achieve.

[image]

What I want to achieve is the highest square.

Oh, before a clever one tells me to simply do what I did on that image, of course the example was faked by cutting a piece of transparent orange to put over the area where the "stick" overlaps with a solid-coloured square. Of course, that solution can't be applied to more irregular or changing shapes, and won't handle the white areas of a picture.

In case it's important, what I'm trying to make with this is a web design in Adobe Illustrator, which would of course eventually end up being made out of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the various blending modes if one of those gets close enough, but barring that, you'll need separate objects. You can't really alter blending on only a portion of a single object.

[image: RGB] [image: CMYK]

Of course in HTML/CSS there are no such things as blending modes so you'll have to either use transparency or not and probably resort to multiple objects there as well.

Comment: css does have blend modes but browser support is limited. See http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/blendmodes/browser-support/

Comment: Uhm, I'm not talking about altering blend on part of an object. That's just how I faked the visual example. What I want to do is to essentially counteract how transparency lightens my colour on a white background. Expressed a bit like algebra, it would be `BaseColor`-`10%opacity`+`x`+`WhiteBackground` = `BaseColor`, and the goal is to find `x`, and the goal is to make x not be opacity. For example, I did something KIND OF like what I wanted by substracting 10% from each R, G and B value, but that wasn't quite it. Saturation and lightness didn't do it either.

Comment: Did you try shift-clicking with the **Eyedropper Tool** in the area which contains the color you want? Shift-clicking with the Eyedropper picks up the color *on screen* as opposed to the color of the object itself.

Comment: @ariene: Christopher John's answer hints at this a little, but doesn't make it explicit: he is using HSB color model and compensating the saturation by the amount of opacity (similar to your RGB algorithm)

Comment: @Scott Sorry for the long delay. I completely forgot about this question. Sorry, it looks like the eyedropper tool doesn't make the same color. So far, the only working method I see is to put a square of the full-opacity color behind the 90 % opacity one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object that you make 90% opacity, you are introducing 10% of the color below that object. In theory, if you were to take your original object at 100% opacity (no transparency) and put the same background color in a layer in front of it at 10% opacity, you'd end up with the same 90%-10% ratio, resulting in the same color as the semi transparent original color.

If you take the result of the non-transparent original with the 10% above it, that is your "darkened" or "lightened" version of the original color.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* work with *some* blending modes *sometimes*...[image: colorKeeperExample: Hard Light] 
 
...as you can see on the "Rainbow-Strip" it's not really flexible. 
You do need them though. I doubt this works with just opacity.

edit: It does kind of work with opacity... [image: colorKeeperExample: Opacity] 
...only I did it the other way around. Here apparently it works by upping the saturation of the 90% transparent picture by 10. Meaning if the original color already has 100% saturation it won't work, (also when using a different color BG, as John mentioned.) 
 That's what I found out anyways..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I completely forgot about this question.